# UITableViewCell with Save button. textField and a label

Tags: swift, uitableview

i want create in swift a tableView with 2 prototype cells, in one cell i've a label and a text field, in other cell i've a save button, the @IBOutlet and @IBAction are in a separated UITableViewCell file, i want write something in Text Field and when click the save button, must change the label.text with textField.text, but i've an issue, when i click the button the value of textField is nil. I'm now in swift, how can resolve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: why are you doing this in 2 different cells? there are only 2 cells? show some code

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is this in pic
[image]

have two files, TableViewController.swift with this inside

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cella", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("saveCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

and second file named TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit
```

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func saveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.label.text = textField.text
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue with the tag

```
cell.propertyName.tag = indexPath.row
```

and this delegate

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        CoreDataController.sharedIstanceCData.matsDataField = "" + textField.text!+string
    } else {
        CoreDataController.sharedIstanceCData.commentDataField = "" + textField.text!+string
    }
    return true
}
```

it resolve my problem, tnx all